# Checkbox property lost after sort is applied

Tags: php, html, checkbox, radio-button

I am working on a website which displays some data that is read from a Database. On this data I want to implement Sorting and Filtering options. 
The features of the webpage are:

- Every Time a filter is applied, the page is loaded again, wherein it builds the query and retrieves the values again from the server where the DB resides.
- Once the filtered result is displayed the properties of the checkboxes are preserved.

The features that I am unable to implement are:

- After the result is displayed I want to sort it based on the user input. However, the problem I am facing is that every time the the user clicks on 'Apply' after selecting a sort radio button, the properties of the checkboxes are lost. As a result, the query that is built again does not recognise the filter options.

Here is the code. I am attaching the the filter and sort div. There is a lot more happening around such as the query building but i feel the problem is rooted to the following code. I am new to php and html and am still learning the basics of web designing.

```
<div style="float: left;margin-left: -175px;" class="box2">
        <h2>Filter by :</h2>
    <form id="ContactForm" name="filter_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method ="post">
        <h3>Location</h3>
        <?php
            $query = "Select DISTINCT LOCATION from venue_list";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            ?>
            <ul>
            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $location = $row['LOCATION'];
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f1" name="location[]" value="<?php echo $location?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['location'])){echo (in_array($location,$_POST['location']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f1"><?php echo $location?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <br>
        <h3>Party Type</h3>
        <?php
            $query = "Select DISTINCT PARTY_TYPE from venue_list";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            ?>
            <ul>
            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $party_type = $row['PARTY_TYPE'];
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f2" name="party_type[]" value="<?php echo $party_type?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['party_type'])){echo (in_array($party_type,$_POST['party_type']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f2"><?php echo $party_type?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <br><h3>Genre</h3>
        <?php
            $query = "Select DISTINCT GENRE from venue_list";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            ?>
            <ul>
            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $genre = $row['GENRE'];
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f3" name="genre[]" value="<?php echo $genre?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['genre'])){echo (in_array($genre,$_POST['genre']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f3"><?php echo $genre?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <br>
        <h3>Happy Hours</h3>
        <?php
            $query = "Select DISTINCT HAPPY_HOURS from venue_list where HAPPY_HOURS like '%M%'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            ?>
            <ul>
            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $happy_hours = $row['HAPPY_HOURS'];
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f4" name="happy_hours[]" value="<?php echo $happy_hours?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['happy_hours'])){echo (in_array($happy_hours,$_POST['happy_hours']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f4"><?php echo $happy_hours?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <br>
        <h3>Outdoor/Rooftop</h3>
        <?php
            $query = "Select DISTINCT OUTDOOR_ROOFTOP from venue_list";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            ?>
            <ul>
            <?php
                $i=0;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $outdoor_rooftop = $row['OUTDOOR_ROOFTOP'];
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f5" name="outdoor_rooftop[]" value="<?php echo $outdoor_rooftop?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['outdoor_rooftop'])){echo (in_array($location,$_POST['outdoor_rooftop']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f5"><?php echo $outdoor_rooftop?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                $i=$i+1;
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <br><br><br>
        <input name="filter_button" type="submit"  value="Apply"  id="filter_button"  class="button"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div style="float: right;margin-right: -100px;" class="box2">
    <h2>Sort by :</h2>
    <form id="ContactForm" name="sort_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method ="post">
        <input type="radio" id="s1" name="sort" value="Name" <?php if (isset($_POST['sort'])){echo 'checked';}?>/>
        <label for="f1"><?php echo 'Name'?></label>
        <input name="sort_button" type="submit"  value="Apply"  id="sort_button"  class="button"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Weirdly, the property of the radio button is preserved but the properties of the checkboxes are lost when apply from Sort pane is clicked. Anticipating the solution to the problem eagerly.

Comment: As you said you are new into web design there´s an observation: 5 queries to the database just to output a form is a lot, you should do the least calls to the database as possible, specially if you are calling the same table all the time. In your case I would work out a better sql Query, get info into 1 array, and filter / sort the array values within php, it will be quicker, and easier to modify

Comment: @aleation Thanks for the tip! Will work on it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different form so

when you submit `Sort` form  it only post your `radio name="sort"` and `submit button name="sort_button"`

why so the property of the radio button is preserved but the properties of the checkboxes are lost.

Use single form to preserve property of chceckboxes.

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't it suffice if i keep the form element separate but the name and id the same? I'm doing that but it is not working. :(